# python tkinter isnt creating another frame inside a frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

For some reason this code refuses to create another frame inside the mainframe. i need for my project to create entry fields in another frame that are weight, fat% and length but I'm having trouble creating another frame... can anyone please help?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import webbrowser


def openweb():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=url1)

#teeb windowi
gui = Tk()
gui.title("FFMI Kalkulaator")
#mainframe
mainframe = ttk.Frame(gui, padding=10, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

#mainfarme ja loob label
label_font = font.Font(family='Timesnewroman', name='label', size=16, weight='bold')
label_ffmi = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="FFMI kalkulaator",font=label_font)
label_ffmi.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan = 5,padx=10, pady=10)
#infoframe ja label
infoframe = ttk.Frame(gui, padding=10, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken")
infoframe.grid(column=1, row=1)
infolabel_font = font.Font(family='Timesnewroman', name='infolabel', size=12,)
infolabel_ffmi = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="See on tervisetööriist, mis võimaldab hinnata teie kehamassi,\n võttes arvesse ka lihaste ja rasvade massi.\n Arvutustes kasutatakse kolme tegurit ja need on kaal,\n keha rasvaprotsent ja pikkus.\n",font=infolabel_font)
infolabel_ffmi.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan = 5,padx=10, pady=10)

#urlbutton ja label
urlbutton = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="click", command=openweb)
urlbutton.grid(column=2, row=2,padx=0, pady=0)
urllabel_font = font.Font(family='Timesnewroman', name='urllabel', size=12,)
urllabel_ffmi = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Saate arvutada oma rasvaprotsenti siin:", font=urllabel_font)
urllabel_ffmi.grid(column=1, row=2,padx=10, pady=10)
url1 = 1
url = "https://www.calculator.net/body-fat-calculator.html"

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you think frames aren't being created inside frames. When I run this code it all seems to do what I would expect.

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When you remove the lines of code that are not crucial here, it'll be easier to find out (also for you) what causes your problem.

Comment: There is no code on creating frame inside `mainframe` in your posted code.